# Opening buttons to Mainwin?

Tags: basic

Using the BASIC language I may open buttons to their own specific window through:
open "Main Menu" for window as #main

This will open the buttons to their own separate window from the main window.  Ideally I'd like the buttons to open in a designated area of the main window, so I can create a menu and user interface for the game I'm coding.

If there is a way to open buttons to the main window, please let me know as it would be much appreciated.

UPDATE: I'm using the JustBasic compiler.

Comment: There's a lot of different contexts in which the BASIC language can exist, not all of which handle windowing in the same way (if at all). Please tell us what environment/software you are using.

Comment: I think it may have something to do with handles, if anyone knows any more.

Comment: At this point would it be possible at all just to keep all the buttons and text in a single window without closing it?   I have multiple sets of buttons that I'd like to have appear and disappear at given times during the game, so that I can have a functioning UI.